# display a banner when a remote notification is received when app is in foreground in xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

i integrated fcm in my xamarin.ios project in xamarin.forms. a banner is displayed when a notification is received when the app is in the background, but in the foreground, i learnt that i have to create one myself. so i tried the following:

```
namespace msging2
{
    public interface INotificationService
    {
         void ShowNotification(string title, string message);
    }
}
```

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(bannerDisplay))]
namespace msging2.iOS
{
    public class bannerDisplay : INotificationService
    {
        public void ShowNotification(string title, string message)
        {
            

            
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
                var bannerHeight = 80;
                var bannerView = new NotificationBannerView(new CGRect(0, -bannerHeight, window.Frame.Width, bannerHeight));
                bannerView.TitleLabel.Text = title;
                bannerView.MessageLabel.Text = message;
                //var notificationBanner = new NotificationBannerView(title, message);
                window.AddSubview(bannerView);

                UIView.Animate(0.3, () =>
                {
                    bannerView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, window.Frame.Width, bannerHeight);
                });

                DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAfter(new DispatchTime(DispatchTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)), () =>
                {
                    UIView.Animate(0.3, () =>
                    {
                        bannerView.Frame = new CGRect(0, -bannerHeight, window.Frame.Width, bannerHeight);
                    }, () =>
                    {
                        bannerView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
  public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 

            
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
               CrossFirebasePushNotification.Current.OnNotificationReceived += Current_OnNotificationReceived;
            }
        }
private void Current_OnNotificationReceived(object source, FirebasePushNotificationDataEventArgs e)
        {Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            DependencyService.Get<INotificationService>().ShowNotification("jj", "uy");
                          //  DisplayAlert("Notification", $"Data: {e.Data["myData"]}", "OK");
                        });
                    }
```

then i send a message from my fcm console, i can see the message in the output of my visual studio, but no banner appears. what am i doing wrong?
thanks in advance

Comment: [xamarin+ios+handle+notifications+in+foreground+vs+background](https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+ios+handle+notifications+in+foreground+vs+background) - Different code is needed to handle notification in foreground, than in background. (I haven't done this in a long time, so I did not look at your code.)

Comment: What version of the iOS test device are you using?